# Big Data : Handling SQL Insert/Update or Merge best line by line or by CSV?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, merge, bigdata

So basically I have a bunch of 1 Gig data files (compressed) with just text files containing JSON data with timestamps and other stuff.

I will be using PHP code to insert this data into MYSQL database.

I will not be able to store these text files in memory! Therefor I have to process each data-file line by line. To do this I am using stream_get_line().

- Some of the data contained will be updates, some will be inserts.

**Question**
Would it be faster to use Insert / Select / Update statements, or create a CSV file and import it that way?

Create a file thats a bulk operation and then execute it from sql?

I need to basically insert data with a primary key that doesnt exist, and update fields on data if the primary key does exist. But I will be doing this in LARGE Quantities.

Performance is always and issue.

**Update**
The table has 22,000 Columns, and only say 10-20 of them do not contain 0.

Comment: Have you thought about using `LOAD DATA INFILE` instead? It can read CSV directly into the database if you format it correctly.

Comment: Was thinking of using LOAD DATA INFILE, only problem is some of the data will be a merge and others will be a insert. @tadman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would load all of the data to a temporary table and let mysql do the heavy lifting.

1. create the temporary table by doing `create table temp_table as select * from live_table where 1=0;`
2. Read the file and create a data product that is compatible for loading with `load data infile`.
3. Load the data into the temporary table and add an index for your primary key
4. Next Isolate you updates by doing a inner query between the live table and the temporary table. walk through and do your updates.
5. remove all of your updates from the temporary (again using an inner join between it and the live table).
6. process all of the inserts with a simple insert into live_table as select * from temp_table.
7. drop the temporary table, go home and have a frosty beverage.

This may be over simplified for your use case but with a little tweaking it should work a treat.

Comment: That's currently the way I was thinking of doing it, will just suck to write the queries being that the main table has 22,000 columns most of which are zero. Is there a way to only import the none zeros and merge them with the main table?

Comment: @JacobSteele You really should design your schema if possible, as 22,000 columns is a really bad idea. What about using an association table where you have ~10-20 values associated with a particular row?